# How to dynamically add a list to a pre exisitng set of lists after a user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So I have a button thats purpose is to add data to my database and when I click the button and the new data is added to my database I want a new list item to appear that will display that new data once it is clicked. All of my code works correctly, my pre-existing links display the data I want them to correctly, and the data does get added to my database. I'm just lost on how I can create another list dynamically.

Here is my current relevant code:

**My HTML:  (`ProjectMainAdmin.html`)**

```
<script>
        function myFnc(x)
        {                
            if (x == "") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            }
            else{   //if a link is clicked
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                } 
                else { // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    //readyState = 4: request finished and response is ready
                    //status = 200: "OK"
                    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
                    }
                }
             //this just for displaying my data from my database to a web page
                xmlhttp.open("GET","get_data.php?q="+x,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
    </script>


    <article>
        <ul style="list-style-type:none">
            <li><a href="#Tiger" onclick="myFnc('G. cuvier')">Tiger</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Hammerhead" onclick="myFnc('S. mokarran')">Hammerhead</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Bull" onclick="myFnc('C. leucas')">Bull</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Great White" onclick="myFnc('C. carcharias')">Great White</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Mako" onclick="myFnc('I. oxyrinchus')">Mako</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Greenland" onclick="myFnc('S. microcephalus')">Greenland</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Whale" onclick="myFnc('R. typus')">Whale</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Thresher" onclick="myFnc('A. vulpinus')">Thresher</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Oceanic" onclick="myFnc('C. longimanus')">Oceanic WhiteTip</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Goblin" onclick="myFnc('M. owstoni')">Goblin</a></li>
            //I want the new list to appear here
        </ul> 
    </article> 

    <div id="txtHint"><b></b></div>   //where the database data is displayed

    <form method="post" action="add_to_records.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="addshark" value="true"/>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add New Shark</legend>
            <label>SpeciesID:<input type="text" name="speciesID" /></label>
            <label>Genus:<input type="text" name="genss" /></label>
            <label>Family:<input type="text" name="famly" /></label>
            <label>Order:<input type="text" name="ordr" /></label>
            <label>Class:<input type="text" name="clss" /></label>
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="add shark" />
    </form>
```

**Here is my PHP (`add_to_records.php`):**

```
<?php     

if (isset($_POST['addshark'])) 
{
    include 'connect.php';    

    $specID = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,trim($_POST['speciesID']));
    $gens = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,trim($_POST['genss']));
    $fam = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,trim($_POST['famly']));
    $ord = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,trim($_POST['ordr']));
    $cls = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,trim($_POST['clss']));

    if (!mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO Species(SpeciesID,Genus,Family,Order_,Class) VALUES ('$specID','$gens','$fam','$ord','$cls')")) 
    {
        die('error inserting new record');
    } 

    echo "shark was added";
    //header('Location: ProjectH.html'); exit;

}

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

**And here is my `get_data.php` if you want to know what it does:**

```
//just displays data from my database to a webpage

<?php 

include 'connect.php';

$q = strval($_GET['q']);

if (!$connect) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
}

$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM Species WHERE SpeciesID = '$q'") or die("fail" . mysqli_error($connect));

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>SpeciesID</th>
<th>Genus</th>
<th>Family</th>
<th>Order</th>
<th>Class</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['SpeciesID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Genus'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Family'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Order_'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Class'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: There are two ways to do it . If you continue with your method , then in the add_to_records.php page , create an array with all the new records and create a session with that array . Now return the pointer to the project main admin page and start session and check whether that session exists or not . If yes , then explode the array and display it in your page . Second method is that insert the values with JQuery / AJAX and display the new records in run time .

Comment: Can you give me a bit of an example of that @PHPWeb?

Comment: Which way you want to go ?

Comment: I guess the first method since Im not that familiar with JQuery and AJAX.

Comment: How you want your new list to appear ?

Comment: @PHPWeb Just right below the <li><a href="#Goblin" onclick="myFnc('M. owstoni')">Goblin</a></li>

Comment: That I understand but I want to know which one will come under href , which one will be passed through myFnc and which one will be displayed as text .

Comment: @PHPWeb the new list should have the variables taken from the new data added in

Comment: @PHP like if the SpeciesID they added in was Dog then href="#Dog" onclick="myFnc('Dog')">Dog</a></li>